# Configuring a third level domain

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, domain, subdomain

I have an Apache instance serving a site on port 8000 of my server (whose ip is 164.177.156.36)

```
Listen 8000

<VirtualHost *:8000>
    ServerName lessico.pistacchioso.com
    DocumentRoot /home/pistacchio/sites/lessico/
    [..]
```

This works if I visit http://164.177.156.36:8000/

On my registry provider (that is not the same a my server provider) i have the following records set:

[image]

pistacchioso.com is the domain i registered and i want lessico.pistacchioso.com to point to http://164.177.156.36:8000/

Those seeweb.it servers are the domain register's ones, i'm ok leaving the mail there (MX) and I can't remove those two NS records (while I can add others).

At the moment, if I visit http://lessico.pistacchioso.com/ I still see the register's courtesy page. The DNS already updated, because pistacchio.com shows apache's standard default page. Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that, for me:

- DNS shows I would expect:

  ```
  james@bodacious-wired:~$host lessico.pistacchioso.com
  lessico.pistacchioso.com is an alias for pistacchioso.com.
  pistacchioso.com has address 164.177.156.36
  ```
- Browsing to `http://164.177.156.36:8000/` appears to show the right page
- Browsing to `http://lessico.pistacchioso.com:8000/` shows the same page
- Browsing `http://lessico.pistacchioso.com/` shows `the default web page for this server.` because `no content has been added, yet.`

I think that what you're missing here is that you're telling the browser to use the `http` protocol - right there in the first 4 characters of the url, `http://`

Browsers understand that, unless another port number is specified, `http` means port 80, so `http://lessico.pistacchioso.com/` is interpreted as if it were `http://lessico.pistacchioso.com:80/`. However, in the snippet you've provided above, you've used `VirtualHost *:8000` to tell Apache to only listen on port 8000 for this request.

This explains why `http://lessico.pistacchioso.com:8000/` works: you're explicitly telling the browser to use port 8000; and you've told Apache to listen on port 8000 and what to do with requests received there.

Change that line to `VirtualHost *:80` and you'll be answering traffic on port 80 instead. The `ServerName` directive you have on the next line ensures that only traffic for the host `lessico.pisacchioso.com` will be handled by this vhost - all other hostnames will still fall back to the default vhost with the default content you're already so familiar with :)

Edited to add:

There's one other wrinkle. You said:

> if I visit http://lessico.pistacchioso.com/ I still see the register's
>   courtesy page. The DNS already updated, because pistacchio.com shows
>   apache's standard default page

That's different from what I see - I get Apache's standard page on `http://lessico.pistacchioso.com/`. I'm guessing that either your DNS host updated something between when you posted and when I responded; or possibly you still have an old record cache. I'd suggest checking this with `host` as I've done above to make sure you're seeing the correct records.

Comment: hi james, thanks for you answer. i changed the virtualhost to listen to *:80 but still on http://164.177.156.36/ and http://pistacchioso.com/  i see apache's default page, on http://www.pistacchioso.com/ and http://lessico.pistacchioso.com/ i see the courtesy page and i'm not able anymore to see the correct page.

Comment: oh, i've also tried cleaning up the system dns cache and browser's. on the other hand, host pistacchioso.com gives the correct ip :\

Comment: If you check Apache's access logs, you should see logs being written when you connect to 164.177.156.36. Do you also see logs being written when you browse to pistacchioso.com?

Comment: http://lessico.pistacchioso.com/ now gives me what looks like the correct page - it's a login form that looks like it's intended to be viewed on a mobile browser.

I'm guessing that your ISP must have some kind of transparent proxy that's still serving up the old page - it definitely looks like your server and dns are now configured correctly

Comment: you are right, thank you. viewing it through a proxy showed me the correct page! do i just have to wait for the isp to refresh its caching? also, how can i configure apache to serve both lessico.pistacchoso.com AND 164.177.156.36:8000? thank you

Comment: Just have two vhosts - one listening on `*:8000` and `*:80`, with the same config in each. To simplify maintenance, you can move the common bits into a separate file and use the Include directive[1] to pull the config into both vhosts. [1]: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#include